# How to compile a .nib file

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nib

If I'm editing a nib file that I decompiled ( https://github.com/akahan/Nib-Decompiler ) from an application, how do I re-compile it into the original uneditable nib format so that I can put it back into the application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [ibtool](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ibtool.1.html). The command line should be something along the lines of:

```
ibtool --compile output.nib input.nib
```

(Yes, output before input; the output name is the argument to the `--compile` flag, while the input name is `ibtool`'s direct object argument.)

You may need other options, depending on your needs; see the manpage for details on all of them.

Comment: Thanks! Tried that, but had input and output switched, and didn't think of looking at the man page.